# Flatten nested MongoDB object with unknown fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to unnest a MongoDB object, perhaps with the $project aggregation, but I do not know exactly which fields will be contained in the object. Is there some type of wildcard that could be used to achieve this?

Eg.

```
{ id : ...,
  details: {
            field1: "value", 
            field2: "value"
           }
}
```

To:

```
{
  field1: "value",
  field2: "value 
}
```

Comment: you can do it `{ field1: "$details.field1", field2: "$details.field2" }` in project stage otherwise you can use $replaceRoot aggregation stage.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am aware that I can project this way per known field. Nonetheless, the field names, in this example field1 and field2, are not known beforehand. So I would need something like #: "$details.#". I'll look into the $replaceRoot suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using $replaceRoot, as suggested by turivishal. Thank you!

```
{
    $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: {
                    $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$details"]
                         }
            }
}
```